# Borrowed value in closure does not live long enough

Tags: rust

I'm trying to play some audio on my Pi, but I have reached a dead end with the `borrowed value does not live long enough`, which does not make sense to me, because I create the variables in `main` and afterwards enter an endless loop. Shouldn't `welcome` & `goodbye` live `main` throughout the program execution?

Full error:

```
error[E0597]: `welcome` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:37:65
   |
37 |                 let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(&welcome)).unwrap();
   |                                                  ---------------^^^^^^^^-
   |                                                  |              |
   |                                                  |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                                  argument requires that `welcome` is borrowed for `'static`
...
54 | }
   | - `welcome` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Line 54 is the closing bracket of 'main'.

What would be the `Rust` way for such a thing? The program basically checks if it should change state and play some audio files if it does change.

```
fn main() {
    // Audio setup
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();

    let welcome = File::open("audio/welcome.mp3").unwrap();
    let goodbye = File::open("audio/bye.mp3").unwrap();

    loop {
        sonar_state.state_tick();
        let state = sonar_state.get_state();

        match state {
            StatusState::OnTrigger => {
                // TODO make this a function where we pass in the file
                let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(&welcome)).unwrap();
                stream_handle.play_raw(source.convert_samples());
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            }
            StatusState::OnTriggerEnd => {
                // Nothing
            }
            StatusState::OffTrigger => {
                let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(&goodbye)).unwrap();
                stream_handle.play_raw(source.convert_samples());
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            }
            StatusState::OffTriggerEnd => {
                // Nothing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The source code in the question doesn't appear to include a closure definition. If at all possible, please provide a minimal example that we can use to reproduce the compilation error you are getting. (Be sure to specify external crates and their versions if needed to reproduce.) At the very least, please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66678087/edit) to include the full error message from the compiler - sometimes the clues are in the details of the message, not just in the general description of "borrowed value does not live long enough".

Comment: @user4815162342 added full error.

Comment: Does the posted answer help?

Comment: @user4815162342 Yes it did, reading the file every iteration works like a charm. I was under the impression I was doing something wrong with the ownerships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell from rodio docs, the issue is that [`play_raw()`](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.13.0/rodio/struct.OutputStreamHandle.html#method.play_raw) sends the stream to a dedicated thread, so you can't send it a reference to a local variable - as far as Rust knows, the thread could outlive the local object. In Rust parlance, `play_raw` requires a `Send + 'static` source.

The other issue is that you cannot have multiple decoders reading the same `File`. Although it may seem ok for multiple handles to "read" from the same source, it's actually not because `File` is stateful, it contains a pointer to how much of the file has been read. This is why methods like `File::read` take `&mut self`.

The solution is to open the file in each loop iteration. For example (untested):

```
fn main() {
    let (_stream, stream_handle) = rodio::OutputStream::try_default().unwrap();

    loop {
        sonar_state.state_tick();
        match sonar_state.get_state() {
            StatusState::OnTrigger => {
                let welcome = File::open("audio/welcome.mp3").unwrap();
                let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(welcome)).unwrap();
                stream_handle.play_raw(source.convert_samples());
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            }
            // ...
            StatusState::OffTrigger => {
                let goodbye = File::open("audio/bye.mp3").unwrap();
                let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(goodbye)).unwrap();
                stream_handle.play_raw(source.convert_samples());
                thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1000));
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Opening the file every time I need it seemed like a waste.

Comment: @MustSeeMelons If you want to avoid multiple opening/reading of the file, you can always pre-load the file into memory and keep it in an `Arc<Vec<u8>>` (`Arc` so it can be shared with a thread). In the loop you can pass to `Decoder::new()` something like `std::io::Cursor::new(contents)`. That will avoid multiple openings of the file, but will require the contents to reside in RAM. You can't re-use the same open file not only due to ownership concerns, but because it would be "spent" (at EOF) after the first usage.