# How to read a file from within a move FnMut closure that runs multiple times?

Tags: file, rust, closures, move-semantics

I'm using `glutin` and so have a move closure for my program's main loop and I'm trying to play an audio file with the `rodio` crate. With the following code everything works and I get one beep every time the program loops:

```rust
...
let sink: rodio::Sink = ...;
event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow | {
    let sound_file = File::open("beep.ogg").unwrap();
    let buf_wrap = BufReader::new(sound_file);
    let source = rodio::Decoder::new(buf_wrap).unwrap();
    sink.append(source);
    ...
});
...
```

However, this is incredibly slow as I'm opening the same file every time it loops, so I try fixing it with the following:

```rust
...
let sound_file = File::open("beep.ogg").unwrap();
event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow | {
    let buf_wrap = BufReader::new(sound_file);
    ...
});
...
```

But now the compiler gives me the following error message:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `sound_file`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/lib.rs:86:33
   |
83 |     let sound_file = File::open("beep.ogg").unwrap();
   |         ---------- captured outer variable
...
86 |         let buf_wrap = BufReader::new(sound_file);
   |                                       ^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `sound_file` has type `File`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I've been trying to fix this for a while now with no success, any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66678087/1600898)?

Comment: If you want to "share" it across multiple closure invocations, then wrap it in `Rc<>` or `Arc<>` depending on if it needs to be `Send`. And in order to be mutable -> wrap it in `RefCell` (or `Mutex<>` !!!) thus getting `Rc<RefCell<File>>` or `Arc<Mutex<File>>.`  But `File` is actually a cursor, so it's not enough to just create a new `BufReader` wrapper in the closure. You'll have to use the`Seek` trait to move the cursor at the beginning of the file on each closure call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The Problem

Basically, the problem at hand is that `rodio::Decoder::new` consumes the value which it reads from (well, actually it is already consumed by `BufReader::new`). So, if you have a loop or a closure that can be called multiple times, you have to come up with a *fresh* value each time. This what `File::open` does in your first code snipped.

In your second code snipped, you only create a `File` *once*, and then try to consume it *multiple* times, which Rust's ownership concept prevents you from doing.

Also notice, that using reference is sadly not really an option with `rodio` since the decoders must be `'static` (see for instance the [`Sink::append`](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.14.0/rodio/struct.Sink.html#method.append) trait bound on `S`).

## The Solution

If you think your file system is a bit slow, and you want to optimize this, then you might actually want to *read* the entire file up-front (which `File::open` doesn't do). Doing this should also provide you with a buffer (e.g. a `Vec<u8>`) that you can clone, and thus allows to repeatedly create *fresh* values that can be consumed by the `Decoder`. Here is an example doing this:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
let sink: rodio::Sink = /*...*/;
// Read file up-front
let mut data = Vec::new();
let mut sound_file = File::open("beep.ogg").unwrap();
sound_file.read_to_end(&mut data).unwrap();

event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow | {
    // Copies the now in-memory file content
    let cloned_data = data.clone();
    // Give the data a `std::io::Read` impl via the `std::io::Cursor` wrapper
    let buffered_file = Cursor::new(cloned_data);
    let source = rodio::Decoder::new(buffered_file).unwrap();
    sink.append(source);
});
```

However, in my personal experience with `rodio` there is still quite a lot of processing being done in the `Decoder`, so I also do the decoding up-front and use a `rodio::source::Buffered` wrapper, like this:

```rust
use std::io::Read;
let sink: rodio::Sink = /*...*/;
// Read & decode file
let sound_file = File::open("beep.ogg").unwrap();
let source = rodio::Decoder::new(file).unwrap();
// store the decoded audio in a buffer
let source_buffered = source.buffered();

// At least in my version, this buffer is lazyly initialized,
// So, maybe, you also want to initialize it here buffer, e.g. via:
//source_buffered.clone().for_each(|_| {})

event_loop.run(move |event, _, control_flow | {
    // Just copy the in-memory decoded buffer and play it
    sink.append(source_buffered.clone());
});
```

If you use this in a multithreaded environment, or if just like statics, you can also use the `lazy_static` crate to make these `rodio::source::Buffered` instance available in the entire program, while doing this initialization only once.

Comment: This was an absolute life-saver thank you! A quick question, what do you mean by initializing `source_buffered`?

Comment: As I said, in my experience, the `Buffered` wrapper gets lazily initialized that means that only when the audio should be played for the first time, the decoder does its decoding thing and this introduces a delay. It is more severe if you have something like an audio effect that should be synchronized with e.g. a visual effect.
By doing `source_buffered.clone().for_each(|_| {})` you force the decoder to do its decoding early on and `Buffered` will directly serve copies without decoding in event loop.